# Zend Select group by Field

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I have a query as below:

```
select status, count(id) as units from myTable group by status
```

I have a Zend_Db_Table object at my displosal for the table in use, i am trying the below mentioned snippet to create the query above:

```
$objTable= new Application_Model_DbTable_MyTable();
$select = $objTable -> select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART)
                    -> setIntegrityCheck(false); // i am also using joins to create the query, but this is not of concern
$select -> columns(array(
           'status' => new Zend_Db_Expr('DISTINCT(STATUS)'),
           'units'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(id)')
           ));
$select -> group('status');
```

the query created from the above snippet is as follows:

```
select myTable.*, DISTINCT(STATUS) as status, COUNT(id) as units from myTable group by status
```

I want to remove the `myTable.*` from the query generated.

Comment: Did you try the simplest? Change `SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART` to `SELECT_WITHOUT_FROM_PART` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$select = $db ->select()
              ->distinct()
              ->from('myTable',array('status', 'COUNT(id) as units'))
              ->group('status');
```

Comment: Its not an optimal solution, as i have to mention the name of table once again, but this definitely worked. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
$select = new Zend_Db_Select;

$select->from(
             # table
             array(
                  't' => 'myTable'
             ),

             # columns
             array(
                 'status' => 'DISTINCT(STATUS)',
                 'units'  => 'COUNT(id)',
             ));
       ->group('status');
```

The problem is `Zend_Db_Select` will automatically added `table.*` to your query if there's no column specified in `->from(` clause